# Trouble with induction on polynomials

Tags: induction

Use induction to prove the following:

$1a)$ Show for all positive integers $n$ that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
$$

$1b)$ Show that if $p$ and $q$ are polynomials so that

$i)$ $q(0)=0$

$ii)$ $p(n)=q(n)-q(n-1)$ for all $n$ that

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n p(i) = q(n)
$$
for all positive integers $n$.

$1c)$ Show that for any polynomial $p$, there exists a polynomial $q$ so that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n p(i) = q(n)
$$
for all positive integers $n$. [Hint: use induction on the degree of $p$ and note that $n^d-(n-1)^d = dn^{d-1}+\textrm{lower order terms}.$]

---

I have for 1a)

Base Case: n=1

$$
\sum_{i=1}^1 i^2 = \frac{1(1+1)(2+1)}{6}=1
$$

Inductive Step:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^1 i^2+(n+1)^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+(n+1)^2=\frac{2n^3+9n^2+13n+6}{6}=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(2n+3)}{6}=\frac{(n+1)((n+1)+1)(2(n+1)+1)}{6}
$$

---

I'm having a hard time understanding 1b) and 1c). I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Hint: telescoping sum

Comment: Try writing out some terms of the first sum and applying the relation you're given - it should be clear from there. For the second, take a derivative, apply the inductive hypothesis, and then integrate.

Answer (score 0):

For 1bii,

$$\sum_{i=1}^n p(i)
=\sum_{i=1}^n (q(i)-q(i-1))
=(q(1)-q(0))+(q(2)-q(1))+...+(q(n)-q(n-1))
$$
and note that
everything cancels out
except
$q(n)-q(0)$.

Note:
I do not think
that the problem
should have assumed that
$q(0) = 0$.